# Putting AngularJs app in docker

Tags: angularjs, docker, dockerfile, bower, blur-admin

I'm new to many things, like docker, gulp and bower. I am using following template - [Blur-admin](https://github.com/akveo/blur-admin), which is angularJs template for creating client side website. I have downloaded this project and made changes to it. Now I want to dockerize this project. Being new to docker, I feel lost in abundance of resources as to where to start or what to write... Please guide me to add a docker file to my code..

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out the docker file content as follows. Might be helpful for someone:-

```
FROM node:6.2.2

RUN npm install --global gulp-cli && \
    npm install --global bower

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
COPY bower.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install && \
    bower install -F --allow-root --config.interactive=false
COPY . /usr/src/app

ENV GULP_COMMAND serve:dist

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c"]
CMD ["gulp $GULP_COMMAND"]
```